# Frontend contact form good practice

Tags: frontend, user-experience, contact-form

What is the good practice about email from a static website? I'm writing one without any backend. I find `mailto:me@contact.com` annoying as it opens the default OS mail client. I may suspect it is not only my problem. But as far as I know, there is no way to build an actual contact form that sends an email without the server. What would be a good solution from the UX point of view?